# How to optimise number of queries when using raw_id_fields in Django Admin

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-orm

I have a data model as below:

```
class Candidate(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()

class Skill(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()

class CandidateSkill(models.Model):
    candidate = models.ForeignKey(Candidate)
    skill = models.ForeignKey(Skill, related_name='candidate_skills')
    proficiency = models.CharField()
```

And in the admin I have:

```
class CandidateSkillInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = CandidateSkill
    fields = ('skill', )
    extra = 0
    raw_id_fields = ('skill',)

class CandidateAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = Candidate
    fields = ('name',)
    inlines = [CandidateSkillInline]
```

Each candidate can have many skills. The problem here is that in the change page for each inline one query will be used to fetch the skill (`SELECT ••• FROM "skill" WHERE "skill"."id" = <id>`). If I add the field `skill` in `CandidateSkillInline` as `read_only` then there won't be extra queries. However I'd like to be able to add new items in the inlines. Thing I've tried:

1) Added custom formset to `CandidateSkillInline`:

```
class CandidateSkillInlineFormset(BaseInlineFormSet):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CandidateSkillInlineFormset, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.queryset = self.queryset.select_related('skill')
```

2) Override the `get_queryset` on the inline:

```
def get_queryset(self, request):
    super(CandidateSkillInline, self).get_queryset(request).select_related('skill')
```

3) Override the `get_queryset` on `CandidateAdmin`:

```
def get_queryset(self, request):
    return super(CandidateAdmin, self).get_queryset(request).prefetch_related('candidate_skills__skill')
```

However, still I get a query for each skill. The only way the queries are not sent is when I set the `skill` in `read_only_fields` in CandidateSkillInilne. The question is how can I select or prefetch the skills in one query rather than one for each inline?

Comment: a bit of a clarification please. You say "Each candidate can have many skills" but what's being modelled here is a Many to Many relationship (without the explicit use of Django's ManyToManyField)

Comment: @e4c5 I've updated the model for more clarification. I need to store the `proficiency` for each skill as well hence need a many to many

Comment: hm, the only change I see is the name field being changed to proficiency, that still makes it a manytomany `through` CandidateSkilll

Comment: the problem still stands after adding `through`, a single query is sent to fetch each skill when rendering the inlines

Comment: where exactly do these extra queries appear? On the list page or the change page?

Comment: in the change page where the inlines are loaded

Comment: maybe you customized your form, that's what happened to be the issue for me

Answer (score 2):

Well, the design of the `ForeignKeyRawIdWidget` is not so elegant. Instead of just show some data in a specific way, which is the basic responsibility of a widget, the `ForeignKeyRawIdWidget` make an extra query to display more pertinent information in the screen (it shows the value of a `str(obj)` method).

The query is executed in the `label_and_url_for_value` method. So, you can try to use your own custom widget to avoid this query, but you will have to think about the tradeoffs in the visualization.

One possible solution:

```
from django.contrib.admin.widgets import ForeignKeyRawIdWidget
from django.urls import reverse

class OptimisedForeignKeyRawIdWidget(ForeignKeyRawIdWidget):
    def label_and_url_for_value(self, value):
        try:
            url = reverse(
                '%s:%s_%s_change' % (
                    self.admin_site.name,
                    self.rel.model._meta.app_label,
                    self.rel.model._meta.object_name.lower(),
                ),
                args=(value,)
            )
        except NoReverseMatch:
            url = ''  # Admin not registered for target model.
        return str(value), url
```

The last step, you will have to set the custom widget in the `ModelForm` class. And there are many ways to do that.

Answer (score 1):

This seems like you are trying to implement your own `ManyToManyField`. Can you use the ManyToManyField and inline instead? It has a nice multiple-select widget in the admin.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#working-with-many-to-many-models